# PlaceFilter for nearby google maps api places

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

In a code i get an ALL nearby places, get names and put in list, what i must to do, where i must write the PlaceFilter for filter by Bar and restoraunts, thx.

Code:

```
   PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
            for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("Place '%s' has likelihood: %g",

                        placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                        placeLikelihood.getLikelihood()));

                listForAd.add(String.valueOf(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName()));



            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            likelyPlaces.release();
        }
    });
```

I am try to do this, but not work

```
List<String> filterType = new ArrayList<String>();
    filterType.add(String.valueOf(Place.TYPE_BAR));
    PlaceFilter filter = new PlaceFilter(false,filterType);
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
            .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [PlaceFilter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceFilter#inherited-constant-summary) is only restricted to PlaceIds not Type.

```
public PlaceFilter (boolean requireOpenNow, Collection<String> restrictToPlaceIds)
```

> restrictToPlaceIds    The place IDs that this filter should allow. If
>   this is specified, only places corresponding to the given IDs will be
>   returned. If null, no filtering by place IDs will be done.

I think filtering the results by the type of place is not yet supported.

Alternative solution are:

Option 1 is try to use [AutocompleteFilter](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/AutocompleteFilter)
Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574649/placefilter-place-type-from-google-places-api-android) how to use it. 
But AutocompleteFilter have only few supported types.

Option 2 is use [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) it allows you to query for place information on a variety of categories, such as: establishments, prominent points of interest, geographic locations, and more. You can search for places either by proximity or a text string. A Place Search returns a list of places along with summary information about each place.

A Nearby Search lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for.

It restricts the results to places matching the specified type. Only one type may be specified (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). [See the list of supported types.](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types)